# How to decrypt a rocksdb file from Android?

Tags: encryption, android, reverse-engineering

I have collected an encrypted RocksDB file from an Android application. By reverse engineering the mobile application I have also collected the encryption key. However, for the life of me I cannot find a client that supports decrypting RocksDB databases.

How do I decrypt a RocksDB database?

Comment: Does the code you are reversing contain the logic to decrypt it?

Comment: No, that code does not seem to be in the APK.